# translate Date in to 1990-03-20 to 19900320 and check the enter with textbox value less-than xml attr value

Tags: php, html, xpath, xquery

this is my xml format :-

```
<products>
  <product_id value="nokia">
    <tab_id value="3550">
      <individual_born_from value="1990-03-20"/>
    </tab_id>
  <products_id>
  <product_id value="samsung">
    <tab_id value="3650">
      <individual_born_from value="1990-03-20"/>
    </tab_id>
  <products_id>
</products>
```

my code:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var xml;
        $.get(
        "xml_converted.xml",
        null,
        function (data) {
            xml = data;
        },
        "xml"
    );
        function get_list() {
        var elName = $('#select').val();
            var xPath = '//product_id["' + elName + '" ' + 
            ' < translate(tab_id/individual_born_from/@value,"-","")]/@value';
            var iterator = xml.evaluate(xPath, xml.documentElement, null,
                XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
            var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            var str = '';
            while (thisNode) {
                if (str) {
                    str += ', ';
                }
                str += thisNode.textContent;
                thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            }
            $("#result").text(str);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="select">
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Search" onclick="get_list()">
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my xpath:-

```
var xPath = '//product_id["' + elName + '" ' + 
            ' < translate(tab_id/individual_born_from/@value,"-","")]/@value';
```

here i want to output something like:-

if user enter date in textbox
if textbox value less-than xml `individual_born_from="1990-03-20"`
then display output :- `1,2` 
b'coz of 1 is first `<product_id>` attr value and 2 is second level `<prodcut_id>`attr value both date are grater-than entered by user in textbox...
if possible with php code using xpath then also help me i add tag PHP
thanks

Comment: The code you've posted is javascript. Can you explain how PHP is related to this?

Comment: @hakre i am not use this js in php i just tell if possible my output using php then please help...

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand. What do you mean?

Comment: i am going to create one demo same like online shopping if any person want to shop one item eg:- i want to buy mobile which realize in less than(before) 1990-03-19 date if this date is build in over xml date like 1990-03-20 is big of 1990-03-19 then its return mobile name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var xPath = '//product_id["' + elName + '" ' + 
            ' < translate(tab_id/individual_born_from/@value,"-","")]/@value';
```

Comment: :( not work i am enter in textbox lessthan value to xml attr value something like this 1990-03-19

Comment: There was a mistake in my answer. Could you try the updated version? And what value are you entering into the textbox?

Comment: try this 1990-03-19 and 19900319 not work any

Comment: `var xPath = '//product_id["' + elName + '" < //individual_born_from/(number(translate(@value,"-","")))]/@value';` i am using this xpath and enter value in textbox `19900319` then its give me error at line 19 this is my 19th line `XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);`

Comment: The XPath you're trying to use is invalid. Did you try my updated XPath above?

Comment: yes i am edited my question now just check with your answered xpath i am enter date in text box but nothing to output...

Comment: finally i done it... this is my final xPath :- `var xPath = '//product_id[translate("' + elName + '","-","") > translate(tab_id/individual_born_from/@value,"-","")]/@value';`

Answer (score 1):

The XPath expression

```
//individual_born_from/(number(translate(@value,'-',''))
```

is valid in XPath 2.0 but not in XPath 1.0, which constrains what can appear after "/" to a simple step.

Comment: `var xPath = '//product_id["' + elName + '" < //individual_born_from/(number(translate(@value,"-","")))]/@value';` i am using this xpath and enter value in textbox `19900319` then its give me error at line 19 this is my 19th line `XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);`